# DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect to persist data from Kafka broker to elastic search using Confluent Platform.

I have written a SinkConnector to persist data to elastic search.

Connect-avro-standalone.properties configuration are:

```
     key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
     value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

But when I push a valid json from the avro producer on to the Kafka it results in below exception.

```
  2016-10-05 15:02:25,225] ERROR Task kafka-elasticsearch-sink1-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:356)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:142)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.UTF32Reader.read(UTF32Reader.java:138)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:153)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1854)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:571)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two different versions of jackson-databind jar in the classpath 2.5.4 and 2.6.3. Deleted 2.5.4 version of the jar from classpath and it fixed the issue.